# Separate title and artists from YouTube title

Tags: javascript

I want to separate title and artists from YouTube title. For ex. If YouTube title is: `Ariana Grande - Problem ft. Iggy Azalea` I want to output sth. like this:

Artists: Ariana Grande, Iggy Azalea

Title: Problem

My script works for title like this who contain `ft, feat or &` but `it fails to separate when a title contains more than one separators.`

For example it falis on this title `Dafina Zeqiri & Ledri Vula ft. Sardi Dj - Got Ur Back`.

It outputs `Dafina Zeqiri, Ledri Vula` as artists but not `Sardi Dj`

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2kyLL6j9/5/

How can I fix this? Thanks.

```
var yt_title, title, artist;
yt_title = 'Ariana Grande - Problem ft. Iggy Azalea'; //this works!
//yt_title = 'capital t feat. 2po2 & lyrical son - facedown';
//yt_title = 'ose Dafina Zeqiri & Ledri Vula ft. Sardi Dj - Got Ur Back';

artist = yt_title.split(" - ")[0].trim();
title = yt_title.split(" - ")[1].trim();

var separators = [" ft. ", " ft ", " feat ", " feat. ", " & "];

//if it has 'ft or other separators' before ( - )
if(title.split(new RegExp(separators.join('|'), 'g'))[1]) {
    artist += ', ' + title.split(new RegExp(separators.join('|'), 'g'))[1].trim();
    title = title.split(new RegExp(separators.join('|'), 'g'))[0].trim();
}

//if it has 'ft or other separators' after ( - )
if(artist.split(new RegExp(separators.join('|'), 'g'))[1]) {
    artist = artist.split(new RegExp(separators.join('|'), 'g'))[0].trim() + ', ' + artist.split(new RegExp(separators.join('|'), 'g'))[1].trim();
}

document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = title;
document.getElementById('artists').innerHTML = artist;
```

Comment: Is your problem set for ALL variations of youtube title?  or just a subset of youtube titles given here in the script?

Comment: My script works for title like this who contain ft, feat or & but it fails to separate when a title contains more than one separators.

Ariana Grande - Problem ft. Iggy Azalea //works
Dafina Zeqiri & Ledri Vula ft. Sardi Dj - Got Ur Back // does not work

Comment: Yes, but do you want your script to work on 'ALL' youtube titles?

Comment: Not all of them, I know its impossible. But I want to include this case. When it contains both `ft.` and `&` for ex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var yt_title, title, artist;
//yt_title = 'Ariana Grande - Problem ft. Iggy Azalea & lyrical son'; //this works!
yt_title = 'Dafina Zeqiri & Ledri Vula ft. Sardi Dj - Got Ur Back ft. Iggy Azalea & lyrical son';
//yt_title = 'capital t feat. 2po2 & lyrical son - facedown';

//rempve string inside () and [] brackets.
yt_title = yt_title.replace(/[(\[].*?[)\]] */g, '').toLowerCase();

artist = yt_title.split(" - ")[0].trim();
title = yt_title.split(" - ")[1].trim();

var separators = [" ft. ", " ft ", " feat ", " feat. ", " & "];

//if it has 'ft or other separators' before ( - )

var artists = '';

var split_title = title.split(new RegExp(separators.join('|'), 'g'));

for(var i=1; i<split_title.length; i++) {
    artists += split_title[i] + ', ';
    title = split_title[0];
}

//if it has 'ft or other separators' after ( - )
var split_artists = artist.split(new RegExp(separators.join('|'), 'g'));

for(var i=0; i<split_artists.length; i++) {
    artists += split_artists[i] + ', ';
}

document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = title;
document.getElementById('artists').innerHTML = artists;
```